# In Rails, how to respond_to irrelevant non-http requests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, error-handling, request, response

I have a relatively large website, and all day everyday it gets hit with requests that are irrelevant from all sorts of IP addresses. A common one is `example.com/home.zip`.

This hits my Home controller, index action `{"controller"=>"home", "action"=>"index", "format"=>"zip"}`. Currently, it causes a 500 error:

`Missing template home/index, application/index with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:zip], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :arb]}`

I imagine the graceful way of handling it is a 404. The closest I've come to a solution is this:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html
  format.any { redirect_to :foo }
end
```

Except of `redirect_to :foo` I would do `render file: "#{Rails.root}/public/404.html", status: 404`.  Am I on the right track?

Comment: Why `format.any` why not `format.zip`?

Comment: @Pavan because it is just an example, it may be not only `.zip`, app is probably being scanned by someone

Comment: @Pavan Exactly as @Vasfed said, `format.zip` would solve the specific error I mentioned, but there are all sorts of formats being requested (json, jpeg, etc).

Comment: Ok, I see. I'd go with routing constraints in this case. Check https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#request-based-constraints

Answer (score 0):

There's no reason to render 404 yourself, you can

```
 raise ActionController::RoutingError.new('Not Found')
```

for this case, also you can make routes constraints a bit harder so that such requests do not hit controller.

Comment: I tried doing a route constraint like this `root to: "home#index", constraints: lambda { |req| req.format == :html }`, and nothing really happened. I was still able to hit `/home.zip` and cause a 500 error. 

I added a `respond_to` block to the index action with ONLY the html format, and now hitting `/home.zip` in localhost says "This site can’t be reached" and the Rails log shows `Completed 406 Not Acceptable`. Is that a better solution than a 404?

Comment: 406 is more descriptive, but there’s probability that scanning script only recognizes 200 and 404, and everything else is treated as “hey, I found an vulnerability, now have to figure out how to exploit”